# Variety of commuting matrices

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, geometric-invariant-theory, commuting-variety

Let $G=\operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\operatorname{Mat}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and let us consider the two varieties $X,Y$ defined as $$X=\{(x,y) \in G \times G \ | \ xy=yx\} $$ and $$Y=\{(x,y) \in \mathfrak{g} \times \mathfrak{g} \ | \ xy=yx\} .$$

The group $G$ acts on both of them by conjugation: I'd like to find out what is known in the literature for the $G$-equivariant cohomology of $X,Y$ (an the mixed Hodge structure on it).Moreover, is the cohomology of their GIT quotients $X//G$, $Y//G$ known too? Is there a relation between them?

Comment: There is a tag for these varieties: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/commuting-variety. It's rarely used, and there are several questions related to the varieties that are not tagged, but it might be helpful in the future.

Comment: The $Y$-version is equivariantly contractible, by rescaling $x$ and $y$ to $0$, so its $G$-equivariant cohomology is trivial.

Comment: Sorry, "trivial" should say $H_G(\text{point})$.

Comment: Are these spaces of tuples? Ordered or unordered?

Comment: You're totally right. As written down before, it was really imprecise. I was meaning couples! Thank you for the editing! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's been a good deal of work since the papers Mark Grant cited.

The rational cohomology of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K)//K$ for $K$ a compact connected Lie group was computed by Stafa (https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.01443). It's a theorem of Florentino and Lawton that if $G$ is a linearly reductive Lie group with maximal compact subgroup $K$, then $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)//G$ deformation retracts to $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K)/K$, so for the general linear group, we can switch to working with the unitary groups instead. Stafa gives a general formula for the Poincare series, in terms of the order of the Weyl group and its action on the (dual of the) Lie algbra of a maximal torus. The formula reduces to $((1+t)^{2n}+(1-t^2)^n)/2$ for $G = U(n)$ (or $GL_n (\mathbb{C})$). Florentino and Silva (https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.07909) computed algebro-geometric refinements of these Poincare series, and their work recovers Stafa's formula.

There's a similar story for the ordinary rational cohomology of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)$, discussed in a paper I wrote with Stafa, https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.05793. Since then D. Kishimoto and M. Takeda have made a good deal of progress, including information about the ring structure and torsion (also they gave a much shorter derivation of the Poincare series).

Regarding equivariant cohomology, Baird has some work in the compact case; see Section 4 of his paper https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0610761. Note that the inclusion of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K)$ into $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)$ is $K$-equivariant and a homotopy equivalence by a result of Pettet and Souto (Geom. and Topol.  17, 2013), and the inclusion of $K$ into $G$ is a homotopy equivalence, so $H_K^* (\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K) \cong H_K^* (\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)) \cong H_G^* \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)$. It would be quite interesting to know more about the equivariant cohomology.

Comment: 1)Reading through Baird's paper it seems to me that the equivariant cohomology of the commuting space  for compact Lie group is actually computed, isn't it ? There is no combinatorial closed expression as far as I can tell,but still an explicit description ( or have I misunderstood the paper?)

Comment: 2) However, why the equation $H_K^* (\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K) \cong H_K^* (\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)$ is true? I imagine would like to say that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,K) \subset (\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n,G)$ is an homotopy equivalence: however this seems to strange to me. The space on the left should be that of (stable) vector bundles while that on the right the one of (stable) Higgs bundle( more or less) which in general do not deform retract one onto the each other. What am I missing? Thank you for the references anyway :)

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio Regarding your comment 1), Baird shows that the equivariant rational cohomology can be computed in terms of torus-equivariant rational cohomology, which is certainly very nice. As you say, one could ask for closed formulas for the Poincare series, and it would also be interesting to have information about torsion. Regarding your comment 2), I edited my answer to explain the relevant result of Pettet and Souto (I'd meant for that to be in there initially, but somehow it got stripped out as I edited...)

Comment: It's worth noting that the analog of Florentino and Lawton's result is false for $\mathbb{Z}^n$ replaced by a surface group. This was shown by Biswas and Florentino using the correspondence with Higgs bundle moduli spaces (and then computing some cohomology groups), so this is very much along the lines of your comment. I would imagine that, similarly, the analog of Pettet and Souto's result fails for representation spaces of surface groups, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Here's the paper of Biswas-Florentino that I mentioned: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0007449711000224

Comment: Really thank you and super detailed answer! So it appears that we know actually the cohomology of these spaces. The mixed Hodge structure of equivariant cohomology seems still unknown however, if I got I well :)

Comment: @TommasoScognamiglio The MHSs are worked out here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.07909.pdf.  Those authors and I are working out a generalization now.  Soon to be announced.

Answer (score 5):

My new paper with Carlos Florentino and Jaime Silva answers this question:

[*Mixed Hodge structures on character varieties of nilpotent groups*.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.07060)

In particular, see Section 4.4.

For an implementation of the MHS in some special cases, please see the Mathematica NB here:

https://github.com/seanlawton/Mixed-Hodge-structures-on-character-varieties-of-nilpotent-groups

Answer (score 3):

There has been some work done by Alejandro Adem and collaborators on the space of commuting tuples of elements in Lie groups, of which your $X=\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$ is a special case. The paper

*Adem, Alejandro; Cohen, Frederick R.*, [**Commuting elements and spaces of homomorphisms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-007-0089-z), Math. Ann. 338, No. 3, 587-626 (2007); erratum ibid. 347, No. 1, 245-248 (2010) [ZBL1131.57003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1131.57003)

contains some basic topological information about these spaces (note there is an erratum from 2010). The later paper

*Adem, Alejandro; Gómez, José Manuel*, [**On the structure of spaces of commuting elements in compact Lie groups**](http://www.arxiv.org/abs/1203.5439), Björner, A. et al., Configuration spaces. Geometry, combinatorics and topology. Pisa: Edizioni della Normale (ISBN 978-88-7642-430-4/pbk; 978-88-7642-431-1/ebook). Centro di Ricerca Matematica Ennio De Giorgi (CRM) Series 14, 1-26 (2012). [ZBL1277.43011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1277.43011)

has some information about equivariant K-theory of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$ when $G$ is compact Lie.

Browsing through these references, I wouldn't be surprised if the equivariant cohomology of $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$ is unknown for $G=\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$.